# java Access parent method from imported child class

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Am a java newbie. Learning from the web. I am stuck with an issue with my code.
I have three class. mainclass.java, oneclass.java, twoclass.java.
I imported oneclass and twoclass in mainclass.

oneclass has a "next" button. What i want to do is onActionEvent on next btn , call a function from mainclass, which would set the visibility of oneclass to false and twoclass to true.
Am posting the whole code for 
mainclass.java

```
    package com.mainclass;
    import com.twoframe.twojframes;
    import com.secondframe.secondjframe;

public class MainClass {
    private static com.secondframe.twoclass panel2;
    private static com.twoframe.oneclass panel1;


    private static void openPanel1(){
      panel1 = new com.twoframe.oneclass();
      panel1.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void toggleVisibility(){
        System.out.println("called from child");
        panel2 = new com.secondframe.twoclass();
        panel2.setVisible(true);
        panel1.setVisible(false);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                openPanel1();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

oneclass.java

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
           //Basically something like -- mainclass.toggleVisibility();

        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to need to post all your code. There are multiple errors in this code, and it sounds like you have further problems.

Comment: what do you mean by "imported" as I can see all you are doing it's to call a static function from another class, (nothing to do with Inheritance).

Comment: @chrylis I posted my MainClass.java code. The oneclass.java just has a jpanel and jbutton and one actionevent added to that button which needs to call togglevisibility() from MainClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "parent" is a class you're extending and the method you're calling is NOT static, the following should do the trick:

```
super.toggleVisibility();
```

If it's a static method - it's even Simpler:

```
ParentClassName.toggleVisibility();
```

Comment: I just posted all my code from MainClass.java. I cant access MainClass.toggleVisibility() from oneclass.java since I import oneclass into MainClass.

Comment: @user2684067 import `MainClass` to OneClass and you'll be able to call its static methods.

Comment: Your "I can't access" statement is incorrect. All that `import` does is to give you a shorthand so you don't have to use the `com.twoframes.thisnthat.ClassName` and can just say `ClassName`. Perhaps you also need to import `MainClass` into your `oneClass`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Once I imported MainClass to oneclass I was able to access the method. I didnt do it cos I was treating the MainClass as the parent and the other classes as its child. So I didnt think it would be right to import a parent class into one of its child. @chrylis The classname is proper in my files, its was just that I was using a different name here and it got mixed up. Thanks a lot everyone for helping out.