# Call parent method from an instance

Tags: java

I was looking at this topic:
[java Access parent method from imported child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243102/java-access-parent-method-from-imported-child-class)

But I'm still not sure the proper terminology for what I'm trying to do.
I have an Instance of Test and I want to call a method from the "parent" that created the instance.

```
public class Main {
    public Main {
        Test test1 = new Test();
    }

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public Test {
        //how do I call Main.showMessage("test is running")?
    }
}
```

**The answer in the topic I listed above was:**

Assuming the "parent" is a class you're extending and the method you're calling is NOT static, the following should do the trick:

`super.toggleVisibility();`

If it's a static method - it's even Simpler:

`Main.showMessage();`

**The issue:**
I'm pretty sure I can't use `super()` cause I'm not extending a class. And I'm not sure if `Main.showMessage();` will work because I haven't referenced the parent `Main` within the `Test` class.

Comment: There is no parent-child relationship shown in your code above.

Comment: Okay so this is the first part of my question. What is it called when you create an instance of a class within another class. What is that relationship called?

Comment: I think you're missing the parameter list (perhaps empty) in the Main constructor.

Comment: So how would you say call a `Main` method from the `Test` class? It's not calling a parent method. It's calling a ____ method?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the desired class and call the desired method:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        //how do I call Main.showMessage("test is running")?
        Main main = new Main();
        main.showMessage("test is running");
    }
}
```

---

As noted by @BrianRoach, by your current code, this will generate a StackOverflowError since it is an infinite loop (`Main` instance that creates a `Test` instance in its constructor that creates a `Test` instance in its constructor ...)

So, another option may be passing a `Main` class instance to `Test` constructor:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(Main main) {
        main.showMessage("test is running");
    }
}
```

Then, in `Main` constructor:

```
public Main() {
    Test test1 = new Test(this);
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors, this would cause an infinite recursion in the OP's code :-D

Comment: I do not believe this works because you create a brand new instance of `Main` in the `Test` class, instead of calling the `Main` that created the instance of `Test`.

Comment: @BrianRoach noted (haha, infinite loop). Fixed the answer.

Comment: @Rawr answer updated. And if you didn't create `Test` instance in `Main` constructor, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an instance of Main into Test, and I'd use an interface to help decouple things:

```
public class Main implements Parent {
   public Main() {
       Test2 test2 = new Test2(this);
   }

   public void showMessage(String message) {
       System.out.println(message);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main();
   }
}

interface Parent {
   void showMessage(String message);
}

class Test2 {
   public Test2(Parent parent) {
       parent.showMessage("I am running from in Test");
   }
}
```